# Draw fixed boxes on HTML canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to web development and working on a project that requires some image editing features. I am using **HTML canvas** for it.

The main step where I'm stuck at is to draw boxes on an image so that if the image is rotated, the drawn boxes should not get rotated (Please refer to the image below):

[IMAGE : Refer this image where the drawn box is not rotated along with the image (expected behaviour)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1HYT.png)

I am storing the coordinates of the boxes along with the dimensions (with respect to image) in an array of objects.

The problems encountered:

- The coordinates of the box change when the image (canvas context) is rotated (as the X and Y coordinates are calculated at an angle from (0,0) (Refer to the exemplary below image)

[IMAGE : Change in position of same coordinates after rotating the context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjgyL.png)

How do I calculate the coordinates after rotation of the context.

Another example is in the below image where I tried to render a big box (indicating image) and a coloured box (indicating boxes to be drawn). I wanted the RED box to start at (0,0) of the BLACK box but after rotating the context, the RED box was not at the expected place.

[IMAGE : Example image with BLACK and RED boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv3z3.png)

P.S. Please feel free to comment down any point that is unclear as this is one fo my initial questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Simply apply the inverse rotation on your box. Pretty sure there are already many dupes though... may not be easy to find.

Comment: You should probably provide the rotation code.

Comment: Your box is the text in the linked case.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/49z3e0xp/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the fiddle. The requirement here is similar to what you've provided but the child box should be fixed with respect to the parent (currently it is moving with parent). How can I determine the coordinates in that case?

Comment: For this you just reset the transformation after you've drawn the rotated rectangle. https://jsfiddle.net/6nt8b25z/